# Can't display image in Image view from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on the android application and I wanna get an image from firebase and display it into Imageview My code works but the image can't display on virtual or real devices.
I tried to display a simple image and it can't show me anything also, so I tried to make it a background image and it works. So I don't know exactly the problem

My Mainactivity.java:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notificationdisplay);
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    final TextView title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
    final TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t);
    //--------------------String text1="";
   FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("notification").child("text").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.v("text:",dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            text.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    //-----------------title
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("notification").child("title").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.v("title:",dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            title.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });
    //-----------------Image
    ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    String url = "gs://my-map-1552492593540.appspot.com/ala.png";
    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(url).into(image);


}
```

And xml file contains:

```
    </TextView>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:text="This is my title field"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textAlignment="center"
```

> 

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingTop="100dp"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/t"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingTop="50dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:text="This is my text field when I want to display my fire base data."
    android:textSize="20dp"></TextView>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_add_alert_black_24dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp" />
```

Comment: it's happening because the image url you're trying to load is not actually a url but some reference string of firebase database!

Comment: Check that your image url is opening in browser or not!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using STORAGE LOCATION of Firebase it will not work
You have to use DOWNLOAD URL as per below image with highlighted

[image: see below image]

Answer (score 0):

The `gs://my-map-1552492593540.appspot.com/ala.png` is a reference to a file on Google Cloud Storage. But Glide doesn't recognize this URL format, so it won't be able to show the image.

To show the image in Glide, you'll need to [get the so-called download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url) of the image.

Something like:

```
String url = "gs://my-map-1552492593540.appspot.com/ala.png";

FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
StorageReference ref = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(url);

storageRef.child("users/me/profile.png").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(uri.toString).into(image);
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle any errors
    }
});
```